# Preserving and Restoring ModelState between Post/Redirect/Get in .NetCore MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1, .net-core-1.1

I m following a pattern on html forms. The pattern is that the user posts the data. If the data is valid, I process it and redirect the user to a new page.

If not, then I redirect the user back to the same page and display the errors on each filled field.

This is following the concept of [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

I achieve this by preserving the ModelState in Temp prior to MVC6. However the ModelState in MVC6 is not serialisable and this approach is no longer doable
[example](https://andrewlock.net/post-redirect-get-using-tempdata-in-asp-net-core/)

How can I still maintain a PRG pattern which is a user friendly and doesn't shock the user with "This will repost the data" message without the TempData?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://andrewlock.net/post-redirect-get-using-tempdata-in-asp-net-core/